# Which brand of USB key storage and external USB storage can prevent wave or wireless read?

Tags: wireless, storage, usb-drive

Which brand of USB key storage and external USB storage can prevent wave or wireless read?

I find some has military encryption USB key storage
, but do I need to encrypt files before saved in these?
Or just drag and drop to these drive , it will encrypt itself

And readable like without encrypt?

Comment: Your question seem to assume that all but some usb sticks allow *"wave or wireless read"*. I don't understand what you mean  with this. This can be because you know something I don't know  yet. It could also be that you've read something and understood it wrong. Or maybe you are talking about something in terms which are unusual. Or maybe your question is missing a specific context. Please provide more details of what you refer to, ideally with references where one can get more information.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by wave or wireless read either. Are you talking about EMSEC (Emissions Security), perhaps? If so, then there are enclosures that are certified to NATO SDIP-27, which is a standard for blocking compromising EM activity, but they are generally very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

The question needs to be more specific, the following is based on a limited knowledge of the question.

If you mean wireless access to the contents of a USB device that would be stated in marketing since such access is a premium product.

Also a battery and charging would be required for data access and that would be in the advertising as it is would be a premium feature.

If you mean contactless such as bank cards and entry tokens that really does not work for data access due to power limitations, data transfer would be very slow and writing data to the device is not possible (writing requires substantial power.

Comment: Why I feel that some people can access without power or even plugin into computer?

Comment: @PrinceMartin What are you talking about?

Comment: I do not have evidence but I really feel that some people can access USB without power and without plugin, is it the CPU or notebook problem or USB key storage problem?

Comment: @PrinceMartin USB _requires_ power. It's not possible to access a USB port without connecting it to a physical interface. Whatever hunches you are having are wrong.

Comment: Is most USB store least power itself so that it can be accessed after no power and disconnect?

Comment: @PrinceMartin No, USB devices do not store any power. They need to receive the 5 volt input from the USB host or they will not function. Only devices that contain chargeable batteries can store power.

Comment: @forest Think a little bigger. Yes, it is possible for a USB device to provide information without being USB connected. My phone is a USB device, that is how I charge it and can also transfer data via USB. It can also transfer data via either WiFi or Bluetooth since it has an internal battery. But consider a flash storage company might make a USB device that also includes a battery and WiFi capability for use on-the-go—oh wait, SanDisk makes one: [Connect Wireless Stick](https://www.sandisk.com/home/mobile-device-storage/connect-wireless-stick).

Comment: @zaph But that's not going to be connecting to PrinceMartin's computer wirelessly without him knowing it.

Comment: Will USB key storage have nano technology that can be charged power with magnetic field then pedestrian steal data?